# Alternative of uxtheme.dll on MacOSX

Tags: macos, drawing

There is a library uxtheme.dll on Windows that allows to render shapes of system elements.

Here is an illustration of what I mean:
http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/images/themesupport.jpg

Is there anything close to that on MacOSX? I am looking for a function:

```
void drawSystemShape(CGContextRef gfx, rect, ctlType, part, state);
```

or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes OS X has APIs to draw system controls in the HIToolbox framework which you can find inside the Carbon framework. The `HIThemeDrawXXX` functions are documented in the header `HITheme.h`.

Even though Carbon is deprecated, those functions are not and also available for 64-bit code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven. Didn't look in Carbon because of that scary word "deprecated"